# GET data from Google REST API , using Service Acocunt

Tags: go, google-api, google-bigquery, google-authentication

I would like to GET information(data) from API and display it. Data is fetched from Big Query by using API.

Currently, I have written the code which potentially supposes to display information from API, but I'm not sure how to use service account as environmental.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

    func main() {

        response, err := http.Get("https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/PROJECT_ID/queries/JOB_ID")
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("%s", err)
            os.Exit(1)
        } else {
            defer response.Body.Close()
            contents, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("%s", err)
                os.Exit(1)
            }
            fmt.Printf("%s\n", string(contents))
        }
    }
```

Expected result should be just to display data from API, then I will need to create an API which can be accessible without authentication with parameters (as GET Method)

P.S. Here is the link to API - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/getQueryResults

Comment: What is your question? 

This is not clear from the example you provided. Are you looking for a way to use environmental variables? If so:


`PROJECT_ID := os.Getenv("PROJECT_ID")`

Comment: @joerivrij they are looking for a way to use the Big query api to access private user data without authentication.

Comment: @DaImTo Nothing related to user's data.  I would like to get information from Big Query result, and I would like to use authentication, BUT use SERVICE ACCOUNT, but not sure how to in these circumstances...

Comment: check the two links i have posted first about setting up your credentials the second is connecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the documentation you will notice it stats [Jobs: getQueryResults](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/getQueryResults) It states that the method you are calling requires that you be authenticated with one of the following scopes.

[image]

The data you are trying to access is private user data you must be authenticated in order to access private user data. You dont appear to be trying to authenticate in any manner.

The service account credentalis you create should be uesd in your code to send an authorization request to google

You can find some information here on how to authenticate with a service account. [introduction to authentication](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authentication/)

- [Setting up credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started)
- [Big query authentication Go](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authentication/getting-started#bigquery-authentication-go)

**Enable credentials**

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="[PATH]"
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/user/Downloads/[FILE_NAME].json"
```

**code**

```
// Sample bigquery-quickstart creates a Google BigQuery dataset.
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "log"

        // Imports the Google Cloud BigQuery client package.
        "cloud.google.com/go/bigquery"
        "golang.org/x/net/context"
)

func main() {
        ctx := context.Background()

        // Sets your Google Cloud Platform project ID.
        projectID := "YOUR_PROJECT_ID"

        // Creates a client.
        client, err := bigquery.NewClient(ctx, projectID)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("Failed to create client: %v", err)
        }

        // Sets the name for the new dataset.
        datasetName := "my_new_dataset"

        // Creates the new BigQuery dataset.
        if err := client.Dataset(datasetName).Create(ctx, &bigquery.DatasetMetadata{}); err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("Failed to create dataset: %v", err)
        }

        fmt.Printf("Dataset created\n")
}
```

Comment: I would like to set up an environmental variable for service account as the actual URL will provide me with the result I need. SO I do not need to query from BigQuery I just need to have a bit of code with will set up an environmental authentications by using Service Account

Comment: As example in python I use - os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "service_account.json"

Comment: I suspect that it will need to point to the full path.   Your not going to be able to use http.get method your going to need to use the sample they give you.

Comment: I have this kind of error by hitting this link - "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",

Comment: I have tried os.Setenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", "/auth/google_bigquery.json") but still do not work

Comment: As well maybe you miss understood, I do not what to QUERY, I would like to use API Url (as it much much faster than to query and display result from BigQuery). My question if more about how to apply a service account to be authenticated during pulling request

Comment: You cant you will need to use the service account to authncate and request an access token then you could apply the access token to the get request if you like.  However coding service account authentication yourself is not easy and i would recommend that you use the library.   If you are looking for an API key type solution there is non for private data api keys are only used for public data.    I understand what you want to do and you cant.  You need to be authenticated and its not a simple matter as putting the credentials on your call some place.

Comment: This may help you get your own implementation of service account authentication working https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount These may help you understand the diffrence [API key](https://www.daimto.com/google-developer-console-create-public-api-key/) vs [service account](https://www.daimto.com/google-developer-console-service-account/)